Why am I getting a ValueError when using classweights
I am trying to train a model in tensorflow and the data is unbalanced so I am using class weights to try and balance the loss function. The outputs in y_train are either 0 or 1. My code is as follows:
class_weight = {0: 1.0, 1: 10.0}

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=[
        tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
    ]
)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, class_weight=class_weight)

When I run it I get the following error:
ValueError: No axis named -1 for object type DataFrame
If I take out the class weights code it runs fine

Is it possible that x_train or y_train is a pandas dataframe? they should be numpy arrays. you can convert the dataframe to numpy with df.to_numpy()

The -1 axis error occurs because TensorFlow expects Numpy arrays for training the models, But your training data (x_train and y_train) might be  in pandas DataFrames. To resolve this, convert your DataFrames into NumPy arrays using df.to_numpy() before feeding them to the model.
Please find the attached gist file for your reference.
